# Can I convert a HFS+ volume to HFSX (case sensitive) without extra software tools?

Tags: macos, hfs

After upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion with added volume encryption along the way, my boot partition wasn't case sensitive any more. Is there a way to convert it back to being case sensitive without reformatting? I know that iPartition claims to be able to do this, but I'm a little hesitant to shell out money for a tool that I'd probably use exactly once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no.

Your money or your time surely will soon be spent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As a follow up, I actually did end up reformatting my boot partition as HFSX. After restoring my Time Machine backup, the partition was back to "normal", i.e. not case sensitive. Pretty frustrating, IMHO.

Comment: After talking to Apple Support, who were very friendly but couldn't really help either, I reformatted once again (as case sensitive), installed a fresh copy of Lion and used the Migration Assistant to recover my data from my Time Machine backup. The Migration assistant makes a surprisingly good job, but left out my changes in a few files in /private/etc.
Be aware that if you want an encrypted boot volume, you'll have to format with an unencrypted file system first, then install and convert it after the installation. Otherwise the install will fail, as I've learned by experience :)